# How can I find the conjugate of $\frac{z}{1+z^2}$ uniquely in function of $z$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm a bit blocked actually, how can I find the conjugate of $\frac{z}{1+z^2}$ uniquely in function of $z$?

Is anyone is able to give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  $\overline {(z^2)}=(\overline z)^2$ and similarly for multiplication/division